# R: If cells of a variable contain a specific text

Tags: r, match

I am trying to find out how many cells contain a specific text for a variable (in this case the "fruits" variable) in R. I tried to use the match () function but could not get the desired result. I tried to use %in% as well but to no avail.

The command which i used is match("apple", lifestyle$fruits) and it returns a value which is much more than the correct answer :X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
sum(grepl("apple", lifestyle$fruits))
```

`grepl` returns a logical TRUE/FALSE vector with TRUE if it is found. `sum` sums these together. You can make this a little faster using the fixed=TRUE argument:

```
sum(grepl("apple", lifestyle$fruits, fixed=TRUE))
```

This tells `grepl` that it doesn't have to spend time making a regular expression and to just match literally.